# Web front-end code compatibility and devices coverage

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, cross-browser

While developing web front-end (html/css/js) certain functionalities are available (say some javascript calls) only with some specific versions of browsers (say IE10+). 
How can I test compatibility of my code or front-end with how many devices ? (e.g. 92% of whole world devices etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/

Look up whatever features/functionality/rules/etc and it will tell you which browsers and versions support it.

Comment: Thanks, great link.

Answer (score 1):

You can check current global usage stats by browser type and version.

[Here (Desktop)](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) and [here (Mobile)](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=1) are examples of these stats, though these reports can easily be found on other sites with the Google query, "browser usage stats by version".

This will give you indication of the market share for the browser you are supporting.

Comment: Thanks, the links you mentioned asks browser name and version. But how can I get with which browser along with version my code is compatible ?

Comment: caniuse.com as mentioned by Dave should help as you likely already saw.